# How to create a rounded gradient in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, gradient

I'm trying to implement this non-linear gradient :

[image: This is design for]

**My question:** I can only create gradient from top to center/bottom to center or from left to center/right to center but it should have some kind of rounded gradient or something. I need to have it the same as on the image above.

Currently I'm using linear gradient for both progress bar and animation inside it but it doesn't what I need.

```
                <Border BorderThickness="1"
                        BorderBrush="#33B8F0"
                        Padding="2"
                        Background="#2F2865"
                        CornerRadius="2">
                    <ProgressBar IsIndeterminate="True"
                                 MinHeight="40"
                                 BorderThickness="0">
                        <ProgressBar.Background>
                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
                                <GradientStop Color="#206fb6" Offset="0.0" />
                                <GradientStop Color="#39437d" Offset="0.2" />
                                <GradientStop Color="#39437d" Offset="0.8" />
                                <GradientStop Color="#206fb6" Offset="1.0" />
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </ProgressBar.Background>
                        <ProgressBar.Foreground>
                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
                                <GradientStop Color="#38e2ff" Offset="0.0" />
                                <GradientStop Color="#78c4fe" Offset="0.1" />
                                <GradientStop Color="#78c4fe" Offset="0.89" />
                                <GradientStop Color="#38e2ff" Offset="1.0" />
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </ProgressBar.Foreground>
                    </ProgressBar>
                </Border>
```

And it looks like this.

[image]

Comment: not sure why you were put on hold i think you question is rather clear

Comment: @DenisSchaf probably because the poster doesn't explain *what* the desired outcome is, or he doesn't just swap the gradients? Your answer assumes the gradient needs to be rounded. Is that what the OP really wants though?

Comment: well okay i guess you can see it like this

Comment: @DenisSchaf like *what*? That's why this question was closed. One of the close votes came from someone with a golden badge on WPF. Clearly, this question needs clarification. Your answer does more to clarify the problem than the question itself

Comment: i never saied you are wrong i just dont agree personally. but i think its toltally fine NOT to share the same thinking

Comment: @DenisSchaf it's not a matter of agreement. Can you clarify this question? If so, it can be reopened. Although it's the OP's job to clarify the question. Right now I'm tempted to reopen but I'm still not sure what the OP wants.

Comment: What does `like on the first picture.` mean? In PowerPoint this would be an outside-in gradient, or a blur.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yeah, thanks for editing my question. It looks better now I've changed the title too so I think it's clearer now for devs. Thanks.

Comment: if i get a question like this:
I wanted to draw a red circle. but i ended up with this *shows picture of a green circle*
what did i do wrong?

Would you a suggest that i tell him that his question is not formal enough and is lacking some information because his handdrawn circle is not perfectly round and he mght also be asking me on how to draw a perfect circle? or would you suggest i just tell him he used the wrong pen.

Comment: And i get you and agree with you its important to ask questions in a proper fashion and that people need to be parented some times to do so. in this exact situation i think it is not nessesary but again: i think its ok not to agree with each other in every point.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos What should I do to unhold this question? I think it's pretty clear what I need to get at the end. No?

Comment: @DmitriyPolyanskiy it needs 4 more reopen votes. Questions don't get closed by themselves. 5 people voted that it's unclear. 5 votes are needed to reopen it. Every edit to the question or reopen vote puts it in a reopen queue where people with enough rep can vote to reopen it or leave it closed.

Comment: It's clear for me now. Thanks.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos seeing how this question developed you were right...this user might need to learn how to ask a question and how to describe an issue and i m sorry for my doubts

Answer (score 3):

This aproach is a little bit unusual but i think it could do the trick for you. You can get the appearance you are looking for by blurring out borders. Please note that the code below is more pseudo-XAML that you will need to adapt to your needs

```
            <Grid Height="20" Width="200">
                <Grid>
                    <Border BorderBrush="#241C59" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="1" Background="#2D255B">
                        <Border BorderBrush="#206fb6" BorderThickness="4" CornerRadius="2" ClipToBounds="True" Margin="-1">
                            <Border.Effect>
                                <BlurEffect Radius="10"/>
                            </Border.Effect>
                        </Border>
                    </Border>
                    <Border Margin="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" BorderThickness="0." Background="#69ABDB" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="50">
                        <Border BorderBrush="#38e2ff" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="2" ClipToBounds="False">
                            <Border.Effect>
                                <BlurEffect Radius="5"/>
                            </Border.Effect>
                        </Border>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
```

Your request:

[image]

the result:

[image]

you might nieed to modify the colors a bit to make it match exactly but gernerally speaking this will do it for you

controls as background can be applied using a visual brush like this:

```
<ProgressBar>
    <ProgressBar.Background>
        <VisualBrush>
            <VisualBrush.Visual>
                <Border BorderBrush="HotPink">
                </Border>
            </VisualBrush.Visual>
        </VisualBrush>
    </ProgressBar.Background>
</ProgressBar>
```

or even better by using a custom control template

EDIT:
As you requested a more detailed version which will show you how to use the prograssbar with a custom control template
normally you would have to use a converter to scale the inner bar to match the percentage. however i was lazy and gave you a solution here that only works if the progressbar is around 100 px widebut should be easy for you to figure out how to use a converter so you can remove the width definitions from this and add a size converter. Cant do all the work for you here :P

```
            <ProgressBar Value="40" Height="20" Width="100">
                <ProgressBar.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="ProgressBar">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ProgressBar">
                                    <Viewbox Stretch="Fill">                                            
                                      <Grid Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Width="102">
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Border BorderBrush="#241C59" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="1" Background="#2D255B">
                                                <Border BorderBrush="#206fb6" BorderThickness="4" CornerRadius="2" ClipToBounds="True" Margin="-1">
                                                    <Border.Effect>
                                                        <BlurEffect Radius="10"/>
                                                    </Border.Effect>
                                                </Border>
                                            </Border>
                                            <Border Margin="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="#69ABDB" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="{TemplateBinding Value}">
                                                <Border BorderBrush="#38e2ff" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="2" ClipToBounds="False">
                                                    <Border.Effect>
                                                        <BlurEffect Radius="5"/>
                                                    </Border.Effect>
                                                </Border>
                                            </Border>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Grid>
                                    </Viewbox>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </ProgressBar.Style>
            </ProgressBar>
```

EDIT 2:

To make this a little more universal we need to find a way to set the width of one control to a relative value. WPF howver is unable to that that, which ia why we need a converter to achive this. This example shows how this progressbar can be made more versatile:

```
 <!--This needs to go into your window resources-->
 <local:NumberToLeftRelativeWidth x:Key="numberToLeftRelativeWidth" />
 <local:NumberToRightRelativeWidth x:Key="numberToRightRelativeWidth" />


 <!--This is the control-->
 <ProgressBar Height="30" Value="80">
                                        <ProgressBar.Style>
                                            <Style TargetType="ProgressBar">
                                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                                    <Setter.Value>
                                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ProgressBar">
                                                                <Grid Height="{TemplateBinding Height}">
                                                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="{TemplateBinding Value, Converter={StaticResource numberToLeftRelativeWidth}, ConverterParameter={TemplateBinding Maximum}}"/>
                                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="{TemplateBinding Value, Converter={StaticResource numberToRightRelativeWidth}, ConverterParameter={TemplateBinding Maximum}}"/>
                                                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                                        <Border Grid.ColumnSpan="2" BorderBrush="#241C59" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="1" Background="#2D255B">
                                                                            <Border BorderBrush="#206fb6" BorderThickness="4" CornerRadius="2" ClipToBounds="True" Margin="-1">
                                                                                <Border.Effect>
                                                                                    <BlurEffect Radius="10"/>
                                                                                </Border.Effect>
                                                                            </Border>
                                                                        </Border>
                                                                    <Border Grid.Column="0" Margin="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="#69ABDB">
                                                                            <Border BorderBrush="#38e2ff" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="2" ClipToBounds="False">
                                                                                <Border.Effect>
                                                                                    <BlurEffect Radius="5"/>
                                                                                </Border.Effect>
                                                                            </Border>
                                                                        </Border>
                                                                </Grid>
                                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                                    </Setter.Value>
                                                </Setter>
                                            </Style>
                                        </ProgressBar.Style>
                                    </ProgressBar>
```

And you will need two converters:

```
    public class NumberToLeftRelativeWidth : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        try
        {
            int width = System.Convert.ToInt32(value);
            int maximum = 100;
            return (new GridLength(width, GridUnitType.Star));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and

```
    public class NumberToRightRelativeWidth : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            try
            {
                int width = System.Convert.ToInt32(value);
                int maximum = 100;
                return (new GridLength((double)(maximum - width), GridUnitType.Star));
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

while this works this is not an ideal solution because this only works if the maximum of the progressbar is 100. This is the case in most scenarios, however if the maximum is != 100 the maximum variable in the converter need to be adjusted. I am open to suggestions on how to improve upon that

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't look good on my end.

Comment: can you elaborate?
xaml should render the same on every machine so it should look just like the picture above which closely resembles the image you started with. the only thing that could influence the outcome of it might be a style that is applied to the border control somewhere in your XAML

Comment: Denis, can  you provide full example how to use your answer in ProgressBar, sorry for being not clear I just don't have enough experience in WPF.

Comment: i updated my answer for you

Comment: Thanks but it still doesn't look good.

Comment: With your new input i can say: good luck

Comment: @DenisSchaf Hi I am using your progress bar I think it looks super good. I am just wondering if there is a normalized way to control the progress amount? When I use 50 for the second border's width, it doesn't fill half of the progress bar. Any ideas?

Comment: @JoanVenge everything below edit 2 is for you

Comment: Thanks a lot Denis, it helped me a lot!